# Extra space printing in last line of console.log

Tags: javascript

one of the Hackerrank problems named Staircase, wants to write a function that takes an integer and prints # sign as staircase and also last line must not have any spaces. so here is what I defined:

```
function staircase(n) {
  let hash = '#';
  for(let i=1; i <= n; i++){
    console.log(hash.repeat(i));
  }
}

staircase(6);
```

and the output in Hackerrank is : (I include line numbers manually on purpose)

```
1 #
2 ##
3 ###
4 ####
5 #####
6 ######
7
```

which is not acceptable because last line (7) is printing extra space. question is why this is happen? does `console.log()` add extra space? and what's the solution?

Runnable snippet:

```js
function staircase(n) {
  let hash = '#';
  for(let i=1; i <= n; i++){
    console.log(hash.repeat(i));
  }
}

staircase(6);
```

Edit: This code is fine in console, it happens only on Hackerrank tests.

Comment: are you referring to the 7th line?  does this not pass hackerrank tests?

Comment: It's probably the result of the last expression evaluated.  Your function returns `undefined`.

Comment: Your code is running correctly. There is no empty line at the end.

Comment: the last line is the value of what is returned by calling your function.

Comment: There is no empty line below. Well not in my console.

Comment: @AtishShakya no problem in console but in Hackerrank it's not accept this and it prints like above.

Comment: @Amy Could you please tell me what last expression and how can I fix it?

Comment: @TheBigAsh You can do it till length 5 and return 6 hash at the end.

Comment: The problem is probably in how hackerrank is calling your function. They probably aren't expecting a console.log() in your function but some sort of return instead.

Comment: Is it maybe a browser problem? This code runs correctly in Node.js, but ".repeat()" is not implemented in all browsers, so maybe that could be causing the issue?! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Comment: @TheBigAsh The last expression in your code is `staircase(6);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Staircase puzzle is a bit misleading, the output doesn't show leading spaces.
You are actually supposed to right-align the staircase, e.g.:

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

(look at the description of the task, there the output is correctly indented)

So something like this should work:

```
function staircase(n) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    console.log(' '.repeat(n-i) + '#'.repeat(i));
}
```

Comment: and yes, i created an account on that website just to answer this question

Comment: Thanks, this is correct. I just wonder why the website shows the result as I show above(I mean right aligned) even if the code is left-aligned!

Comment: @TheBigAsh probably they `trim()` the output, which makes this question a bit "evil"